# YoloV3 : undefined symbol: _ZN9_IplImageC1ERKN2cv3MatE when Build with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, yolo, darknet

I use https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet to run Yolo V3 and darknet is built using OpenCV 3.4.0.

When I tried to run this command `./darknet detector train data/obj.data cfg/objyolov3.cfg darknet53.conv.74` to train my own dataset, with `OPENCV = 0` training works successfully, but when I build with `OPENCV=1`, I got this following error :

```
Loading weights from darknet53.conv.74...
 seen 64 
Done!
Learning Rate: 0.001, Momentum: 0.9, Decay: 0.0005
 If error occurs - run training with flag: -dont_show 
Resizing
896 x 896 
./darknet: symbol lookup error: ./darknet: undefined symbol: _ZN9_IplImageC1ERKN2cv3MatE
```

The chart image showed up but closed immediately, adding `-dont_show` also not helping. I couldn't find similar problem on the internet, any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is very rare to encounter this problem. But I managed to solve it after discussed it with the repo's author. Insted building darknet using `make`, it works when I built darknet using `cmake`.

- Edit CMakeLists.txt in darknet folder and add this line : `SET(OpenCV_DIR /home/<Change this to your OPENCV path installation>/OpenCV-3.4.0/share/OpenCV/)`
- `cmake .`
- `make`

Original github issue : https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/2489

Comment: I dont see a CMakeLists.txt file in the darknet repo. What version of darknet are you using and where is the txt file?